# New type in C# with design time checking

Tags: c#, types

Based on this thread.

[Define "custom" integer-based type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615113/define-custom-integer-based-type)

The Answer above is great, but how can I get a error at designtime/compiletime and not only at runtime.

If I say

```
byte b = 300; //This will not compile.
```

So how can I get the same behaviour for

```
PackedValue p = 5000;
```

or in this case because of the explicit

```
PackedValue p = (PackedValue)5000;
```

Comment: What is the max and min value you are planning for your type?

Comment: @Crono Unless you provide a `implicit` operator, else it is fine

Comment: Check implicit operators, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: @Maarten, implicit, explicit would not solve my designtime issue.

Comment: @Sriram. Based on the example I'm refering to, 12 bit, which gives 0 - 4095.

Answer (score 5):

This is difficult, but you might want to look into **[Code Contracts](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970)**, an extension for Visual Studio which allows you to specify **custom compile-time checks** for your code.

Using this, you can include lines in your operator declarations (both implicit and explicit) such as:

```
Contract.Requires(val < (1<<12));
```

This will generate a compile-time error when violated, e.g. with your example above.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have a look at this, but since other people will also be using my classes/code I don't want them to rely on extensions to the environment.